# Is there an alternative to ViewDidLoad? Any other place to write code which needs to be activated, when a viewController loads?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, nsuserdefaults

I have a `viewController` which holds three text fields. Each text field is connected to a label and uses `NSUser Default` so that when a user writes something in the textfield, the text is saved with a key - and showed in the label assigned to it. That works fine.

Two of the three text field are for the user to write "a question" and an "extra identifier". In case the user don't know what to write in these, in the top of the screen there are two buttons leading to two different `tableViewControllers` - both of which holds tableViews with inspiration/options that the user can choose. I implemented a segue from each, so that when the user taps a `tableViewCell`, the text in this cell is passed to the right textfield in `viewController1` - and the user can now press save and save this text in the `NSUser Default` and let it be shown in the assigned label.

The problem is that these segues are ofcourse using ViewDidLoad to show the passed text from the inspiration tableViews. This means that when you enter the second tableViewController with inspiration after saving you chosen "question" from the first, then - because of the `viewDidLoad` method - all textfields and labels are cleared again and only the thing you just passed in there is shown... So:

Can I use another method than `viewDidLoad` to pass the data into ViewController1?

Or can I maybe add some code to the viewDidLoad method, so that it stops "resetting" all labels and textfields every time you enter the `viewController`?

Or do I need to go about it all a completely different way?

I hope it all makes sense - sorry about the long explanation! :D

Here's the relevant code from viewController1:

```
var chosenQuestion:String = ""
var chosenIdentifier:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
DiaryQuestionTextField.text = chosenQuestion
RandomIdentifierTextField.text = chosenIdentifier
}


@IBAction func WriteDiaryName() {

    let title = "You have now chosen you diary's name. \n \n Do you wish to save this name and continue? \n \n You can always change all the details."
    let alert =  UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.defaults.setValue(self.DiaryNameTextField.text, forKey: "DiaryNameKey")
        let NewDiaryName = self.defaults.string(forKey: "DiaryNameKey")
        self.DiaryNameLabel.text = NewDiaryName

    }))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And there is ofcourse two similar methods for "WriteQuestion" and "WriteExtraIdentifier".

And here's the relevant code from one of the two `tableViewControllers` with "inspiration":

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.destination is UpdatingIdentifiers {
        let vc = segue.destination as? UpdatingIdentifiers
        let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRowIndex!)
        let label = cell?.viewWithTag(420) as! UILabel
        vc?.chosenQuestion = label.text!
    }
}
```

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: "A picture is worth a thousand words" Can you add a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: _Swift Tip:_ all Swift variable and func names should be `lowerCamelCase` - yours are `UpperCamelCase` which makes them hard to tell from class names

Comment: I think `ViewWillAppear()` and `ViewDidAppear()`is best alternative of `ViewDidLoad()` in `ViewController`.

Comment: I added two photos of my storyboard in the bottom of the question. But do you think with this issue, that viewDidLoad and viedDidAppear will be any different? I mean the problem is that every time the given method runs, both the "question-textfield" and the "identifier-textfield" is updated. Which means one of the turns out empty and one updated..

Comment: The only thing I can think of is trying to implement some sort of if-sentence, which says: if textfield is empty, then you should update it with the new informartion - if else: Keep the info, that is in there!. But I'm not sure how to formulate it... Do you get me?

Comment: Hard to be sure, but it looks as though your question view controller is pushing on a suggestions view controller, which in turn is pushing on a _new_  question view controller. Instead, you should just pop _back_ from the suggestions to the existing question. Use a delegate protocol or closure to pass values back, or set a selected suggestion property on suggestions and use an unwind segue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use a **`closure`** approach for this scenario.

1. Create a `closure` variable in `ViewController2`.
2. Set the value of this `closure` whenever you present `ViewController2` from `ViewController1`.
3. Call the `closure` whenever you select a row in `tableView` of `ViewController2` and pass the selected value in the `closure`.
4. Update the `chosenQuestion` whenever you get a new value from `closure` using which in turn will update the `textField's` value using the `property observer`.

**Example Code:**

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var DiaryQuestionTextField: UITextField!

    var chosenQuestion = "" {
        didSet{
            //Textfield will be updated everytime a new value is set in chosenQuestion variable
            self.DiaryQuestionTextField.text = self.chosenQuestion
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showInspirationVC(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        controller.handler = {[weak self](data) in
            self?.chosenQuestion = data
        }
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    var handler: ((String)->())?
    var data = ["Question-1", "Question-2", "Question-3", "Question-4", "Question-5"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.handler?(self.data[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
}
```

**Storyboard:**

[image]

Try implementing a simple use case first. And you don't need segues in this approach since you are presenting the controller programatically.

Let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: I implemented these - but it gives me the error:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on this line:  self.DiaryQuestionTextField.text = self.chosenQuestion

Comment: @AntonBjerg What? Please elaborate.

Comment: Also, is there a reason, that you in that example has the tableViewController as both a "UIViewController" and "UITableViewDelegate". Because right now both of my tableViewControllers are just "UITableViewController". Does this make any difference in this matter?

Comment: No it doesn't. You can use either a `UIViewController` + `UITableView` or a `UITableViewController` totally depending on your requirement. In case your controller contains just a single` UITableView`, it's better to use `UITableViewController`. In this example, I just tried to explain the `closure` approach that you can use to communicate b/w 2 controllers.

Comment: After implementing these new methods of yours, the app chrashes, when I select a cell in the inspiration tableView - and then gives me the error about finding nil after unwrapping... What I wrote above - on the line, that I wrote above. But I don't understand why these changes should have turned chosenQuestion into nil?

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the explanation! - I just mentioned a difference and then you never know...  Maybe that little difference in you code and mine was the cause of all my issues!

Comment: Add the code that you have used. And Make sure all the outlets are connected and you have implemented tableView's dataSource methods.

Comment: I have my own original code + your extra already. All outlets are connected fine - and as far as I know, I would get error before running, if I had not implemented the dataSource methods correct, right?  

Can you maybe ellaborate step nr. 2 in your "guide"? I'm not sure I understand this completely. Might be where I have done something wrong.

Comment: Should my prepare(for segue: method still be implemented? Or should I refer to chosenQuestion inside the didSelectRow method now? Where you wrote "add you data here"?

Comment: Okay.... Two places in your code that confuses me: 1. "Add you data here". I don't know what to write in there for the 'handler' to pass the right stuff?  2. This line: self?.chosenQuestion = data.     What is "data"? Where do i refer to it? I get the feeling, I should write something here - I don't know what

Comment: Wauw!! After deleting my segues and the prepare for segue - method, things are working (almost!!)! Now when I press a cell, it passes "data", which stays in viewController1 - that's amazing! Thanks a lot! ... Only.. I really can't figure out how to refer to one specifik cell's text. I that something you can help me with? To get this to actually work in function! And do you in that case need to see excactly how i populated the tableview?

Comment: You see - right now, it passes whatever string I write in the handler ("IN HERE!") - but how do i refer i a chosen cell's text in there?

Comment: It works perfect now!
Don't know how I would have figured all that out without your help! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sure. Happy coding..:)

Comment: Thanks! One small thing: Now that I don't use segues to get to the two tableViewControllers anymore - and they therefore are not embeded in the navigationController, the top bar disappeared...? How do I get that back? :) Just with the title up there!

Comment: Try pushing the `ViewControlle2` instead of presenting it. `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)`

Comment: Hmm.. Well that working for the trouble about the topbar - the top bar shows, when pushing instead of presenting. But for some reason it destroys the cell's passing data function. Now, for some reason, the cell is deactivated and can't pass the data anymore... I don't see what these two methods had to do with eachother?

Answer (score -1):

Simple, you just need to re-initialise "chosenQuestion" and "chosenIdentifier" with the values from UserDefaults in the viewDidLoad and you are good to go.